Behavior of PID circuit
I am trying to design a PI circuit.
I am having trouble tuning this PI circuit on LTSPICE. Here is my circuit.

The op amp I use is the Universal Op Amp 4 from LTSPICE generic components.

Brief circuit explanation. I want the output of the circuit PI_OUT to follow the opposite of SETPOINT or if you want the input/4. SETPOINT is -input/4. SETPOINT is directly connected back to the other input of the PI circuit. After a buffering stage, the two inputs go into an instrumentation amplifier which generate an error signal. The error is distributed between integrator and proportional stages. These stages outputs are then summed together.
I cannot seem to find parameters that make this feedback loop work. When I increase the proportional gain, the output starts to oscillate before even reproducing the SETPOINT.
In the picture below you can see a simulation where the feedback resistor of the proportional stage is varied from 100 to 700. You can see that some spurious oscillations are added to the output at RF= 600, which is a proportional gain lower than 1, at the same time you can see that before the oscillations onset the amplitude of the sine wave is much lower than the set point. However the DC set point seems to be reached adequately.

Here is for a square wave with RF=500, just before the proportional stages starts to oscillate. You can see that I do not reproduce the square wave while oscillations are already appearing.

Q: What am I missing here? What are the things I should be careful about to make this work, at least in theory ?

Start with your system transfer function. BTW, your whole circuit could be simplified appreciably. Besides not being wired properly, Why are you using an instrumentation amp as the error amp?
